# All users in a group must approve workflow task - Custom Visual Studio Workflow - SharePoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-workflow

I have a custom workflow done in Visual Studio 2010 (for SharePoint 2010 site). I have a task assigned to a group. All users receive task assignment notification emails without any problem. By default any of them approving it shows the task as completed.

My task will be considered approved only when ALL members of the group approve that. How to achieve this please?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've seen multi-approval workflows, it has always included multiple tasks. I don't think a single task can be some percentage approved. It's either pending or approved (or denied, etc).

I can think of two possibilities:

1. In your custom workflow, at the time that the task is being assigned, rather than assigning a single task to the group, assign one task to each member of the group.
2. Add an ItemUpdating event receiver to the Task list item that maintains (another list, database, etc?) a list of users have approved the task. Once all users in the group have approved the task, allow the update to go through, otherwise leave the status as pending.

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested that a Replicator Activity with Until condition is the proper way to go for this. As per my research this sounds like a good solution.

http://wiki.windowsworkflowfoundation.eu/default.aspx/WF/UntilConditionAndTheReplicatorActivity.html

I welcome any further suggestions/approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping track of the number of individual tasks assigned and individual tasks completed.  When completed==assigned, check to make sure all tasks resulted in approval and take the required action from there.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could create a custom task type that uses a different field, and store all of the user names in it, and check them off one by one with a custom task form... but it's actually a lot simpler if you create multiple tasks in parallel.

Here is an example of how to do it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128696.aspx (Watch the video too!) BUT-- there is one part of his example that's a bad practice: he initializes the InitialChildData IList inside the Initialzed event of the Replicator activity... that's why he has to initialize the first child in there, and the rest in the ChildInitialized event... the correct way is to have a code activity run immediately before you get to the replicator and set up your IList. Then you can just leave all of the actual initialization code in the childInitialized handler. In my real life working version I have no replicator initialized handler at all.

I'm about to go into an example that goes along with the Scot Hilier one linked above, like an errata addendum type thing, so don't get upset when you realize this code isn't the entire solution.

For example, if my multi approver list is using a comma delimited string property of my workflow called Assignees (maybe I get it from the intialization data of the workflow, maybe a previous task form... that's your own business)

```
private void prepareCodeActivity_Invoked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Assignees = DesignatedApprovers.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    }
```

Assignees is a List<string> in this case, and I have bound the InitialChildData property of the replicator to it

```
private void replicateTasks_ChildInitialized(object sender, ReplicatorChildEventArgs e) {
        // do all of your task setup here (e.InstanceData is the single string for this child)
        // note I'm setting properties of my custom activity, not the task itself
        // each child instance of the replicator gets it's own instance of it.

        generalApprovalTask.TaskAssignedTo = e.InstanceData.ToString();
        generalApprovalTask.TaskTitle = string.Format(MyStrings.GeneralApprovalTaskTitle,
                    workflowProperties.Item.File.Name)

        // log something!
    }
```

Just a small oversight by Mr Hillier, but it's generally a good example, so we'll forgive him.

If you want to examine the results, do it in the ChildCompleted handler of the replicator. (Mr Hilier does not cover this part either.)

```
public int FailedApprovals { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called upon the completion of the child tasks. Here is where we check the outcome.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void replicateTasks_ChildCompleted(object sender, ReplicatorChildEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Activity is MyGeneralApprovalTaskActivity) {
            var act = e.Activity as MyGeneralApprovalTaskActivity;
            if (act.TheTaskOutcome != MyStrings.ApprovedString) {
                FailedApprovals++;
            }

            // log something!
        }
    }
```